# Is there a java-library for rendering with a voxel-engine?

Tags: java, rendering, voxel

I'm interested if there are libraries in java, that render [voxel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel)-based sceneries? Open-Source is preferred, as always.

Comment: So you've also read that c't article?  :)

Comment: Ja, das habe ich tatsächlich und es hat mich daran erinnert, dass es etwas vor Polygonen gab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some attempts to support Voxels with the now late J3D.
[Here are some examples](http://java3d.j3d.org/tutorials/quick_fix/volume.html)

There was also a project from university of Iowa a few years ago, called VolumeJ, but that [project](http://webscreen.ophth.uiowa.edu/bij/vr.htm) is fairly old.

Finally, there were a recent [academic survey](http://spiedl.aip.org/getabs/servlet/GetabsServlet?prog=normal&id=PSISDG006918000001691804000001&idtype=cvips&gifs=yes) about these frameworks, I am sure that there is a free PDF somewhere.